# Is it possible to return the messages that are generated and shown in SSMS to the calling application(page, console app, etc)?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

We are planning to add a feature to an Admin page of our website that will allow us to trigger the "Index Reorganization" in SSMS with a progress bar.  We would love to be able to return the generated messages to a text box on the page and then base the progress off of those instead.  I've seen the options to have them sent to a file, but we are wanting the user to be able to perform this from the website solely.  Is this a possibility?

Comment: While this sounds like a nightmare feature, this depends on your development language / environment. SSMS is, after all, just an application written in .Net language.

Comment: Using Subsonic with ASP.Net Web Forms with AJAX and Telerik AJAX controls for UI, C#, JavaScript, jQuery